How to Integrate NopCommerce with an Angular Template for E-commerce?
I’m currently working on a grocery e-commerce site for a new client and am looking for the best approach to minimize development time. I know only .NET and Angular, so I’m considering downloading NopCommerce from GitHub and integrating it with a grocery Angular template that I plan to purchase from ThemeForest.
Here are some of my concerns:

Customization: Will I be able to effectively customize the pre-made template to fit the specific needs of a grocery store (e.g., product filtering, displaying perishable items)?
Integration: How smooth will the integration process be between nopCommerce and the Angular template? Are there potential compatibility issues?
Long-term maintenance: Are there any potential drawbacks to this approach in terms of future maintenance and updates?

I'm open to all suggestions and would appreciate any insights from experienced developers who have tackled similar projects using .NET and Angular.
Additionally, if anyone has alternative recommendations for building a grocery e-commerce site quickly and efficiently within these technology constraints, please share your thoughts!
Thanks in advance for your valuable input!
I have downloaded the source code from Git Hub and run the NopCommerce project. the UI screens are not suitable for my requirement, so i decided to use existing templates
